# Online food ordering system database design. New table for each restaurants menu or single one?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I need help figuring out how should I design the database (DB) of an online food ordering system.
Should I create a new table for each restaurant menu or a single one? If single menu, how do I link it to the restaurant while querying for all dishes of a single restaurant?

Comment: One table for all restaurants.  One table for all menus.  Those are *entities* in the database.  Proliferation of tables would be a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant
(
    RestaurantID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Name        VARCHAR(150)
    ,Address1    VARCHAR(150)
    ,Address2    VARCHAR(150)
    ,City        VARCHAR(150)
    ,State       VARCHAR(150)
    ,Zip         VARCHAR(10)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE Menu
(
    MenuID        INT         PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Name         VARCHAR(150)
    ,RestaurantID INT         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Restaurant (RestaurantID)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE MenuItem
(
    MenuItemID   INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,MenuID      INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Menu (MenuID)
    ,Name        VARCHAR(150)
    ,Description VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,Price       DECIMAL(8, 2)
);
GO

CREATE PROC usp_GetRestaurantMenu
(
    @RestaurantID INT
)
AS
SELECT  r.Name AS RestaurantName
        ,mi.Name AS MenuItem
        ,mi.Description AS MenuItemDescription
        ,mi.Price
FROM    dbo.Restaurant AS r
        INNER JOIN dbo.Menu AS m ON m.RestaurantID = r.RestaurantID
        INNER JOIN dbo.MenuItem AS mi ON mi.MenuID = m.MenuID
WHERE   r.RestaurantID = @RestaurantID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the propose structure of

Restaurant >>   Menu  >>    MenuItem

and based on my experience of working on systems like [food-ordering.co.uk](https://www.food-ordering.co.uk) I would actually propose the introduction of a Category (eg. Starters), as follows:

Restaurant   >>   Menu   >>     Category   >>      MenuItem

That way you would be able to do things like having an "Easter Menu"  or "Lunch menu" and "Dinner Menu" each one with its own Categories of dishes which your system could show depending on the date or time of the day.

There are certainly workaround and various ways of implementing this but I hope this suggestions helps.  Obviously it would make the PROC usp_GetRestaurantMenu  (based on Mike Petri's code) slower as you would need  additional JOIN and adding one more level to the menu structure, but it all depends on what functionality/flexibility you want to implement and how you want to balance this with performance.